# comma seperataed data in csv cell into numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, csv, numpy

I am using python to read data from .csv file. The .csv file has saved data in one cell(col3 data) separated by commas. I want to put these data in numpy array.
The dataset looks like bellow

```
col1     col2     col3
1        1        1,2,3,4,...
2        2        1,2,3,4,...
3        3        1,2,3,4,...
```

[dataset.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gB0i.png)

Can someone help me to read .csv file col3 data and save into numpy array?
The data in col3 is really big, one cell has 1080 data. I tried to  save these data in separated columns using pandas but since .csv file only has 255 columns, it doesn't save all the data.

Thank you

Comment: That `png` image isn't a `csv` text file. What is the delimiter for the 3 'main' columns?  tab?  white space?  It's hard to mix that kind of column with the `,` separation for `ranges`.

Comment: Read it in as is (separated by whitespace), then split col3 on the comma, as per the duplicate question.

Comment: It is just the format of .csv file. In column3 data(ranges) saved into cell separated by using commas. There is 1080 data in one cell. What I want to do is, add those column3(ranges) data into numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.col3.str.split(',', expand=True).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').values
```